# Conocer el tamaño de una carpeta en python

Tags: python

Estoy con un programa y necesito saber tamaños de carpetas y archivos para comprobar sus tamaños.

Aplicando esto se que puedo conocer el tamaño de los archivos:

```
import os
sizefile = os.path.getsize('C:\\user\\folder\\archivo.txt')
print(sizefile)
```

Pero, ¿para carpetas? Se me ocurre entrar en la carpeta ver el peso uno a uno y sumarlo. Pero me parece raro que no haya un comando que lo haga directamente (yo no lo encuentro). ¿Como se suele hacer?

Gracias.

Comment: No lo hay, ni en el command prompt ni en python (se me había ocurrido hacer un subprocess pero no)... Windows!

Answer (score 2):

Desconozco si hay alguna forma de hacerlo como dices, pero he mejorado el código proporcionado por Rubiales Alberto. Quedaría así:

```
def calcular_directorio(directorio): return sum([sum([os.path.getsize(rutas+"\\"+archivo) for archivo in archivos]) for rutas, _, archivos in os.walk(directorio)])
```

Cuando llames a la función, has de poner una 'r' delante del directorio (`print("Peso de la carpeta: "+str(calcular_directorio(r"C:\Users\roger\Documents\Python")))`).

Espero que sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Pues no hay otra forma. Hay que hacer lo que tú has dicho, tienes que crear un bucle que itere por todos los archivos y subdirectorios.

```
import os

def calculador_tamaño(fichero):
    tamaño_total = 0
    for rutas, directorios, archivos in os.walk(fichero):
        for archivo in arhivos:
            subarchivo = os.path.join(dirpath, archivo)
            if not os.path.islink(subarchivo):
                tamaño_total += os.path.getsize(subarchivo)

    return tamaño_total
```

Te dejo esta función, puedes mejorarla poniéndole más parámetros para que te devuelva el tamaño en megas, gigas, etc.